# Input field validation action/filter hook for Gravity Forms

Tags: forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a Gravity Forms form configuration that contains an input field for the user to type in a value. For now it's just a single line text field. I need to perform validation on this field - preferably upon leaving the field by way of Ajax.

I'm writing a plugin that uses GFAPI and `gform_after_submission` to process submitted data.

Does Gravity Forms provide actions/hooks for validation by way of Ajax?

Basically, I'm looking for a way to validate an ID that is to be entered by the user on the frontend. If the ID matches some criteria (which includes a database lookup) then I return true or false in an Ajax response.

I see gform_field_validation, but this is intended for when the entire form is submitted, I think. I need to perform validation upon leaving/entering a field, etc. by Ajax.

How can this be accomplished with a Gravity Form?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, gravity forms does not provide client side validation:

see this article: https://www.parorrey.com/blog/front-end-development/wordpress-gravity-forms-validation-on-client-side-using-jquery/

---

For your specific situation i would suggest the following:

in your javascript file:

```
(function($){
$.validator.addMethod("validateID", function(value, element) {
   //do your db lookup here and run the necessary checks
   return value === "stackoverflow";
 }, "Please enter in a valid ID");

 $("form").validate({
  rules:{
    customer_id: {
    validateID: true
    }
  }
 });

 $("form").on('submit',function(){
 return false;
 });
})(jQuery)
```

JsFiddle Link:

https://jsfiddle.net/craigiswayne/xpvt214o/214343/